# Array has been initialized but still "array required but int found "

Tags: java

```
count = 0;
String s5 = "Select count(username) from login;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s5);

while(rs.next()) {
  count=rs.getInt(1);
}

int num[] = new int[count];
String s3 = "Select username from login;";
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(s3);

while(rs2.next()) {
  String user=rs2.getString(1);
  for(i=0 ; i<count ; i++) {
    count[i] = user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`num` is an array. `count` is not. Change `count[i]=user;` to something like

```
num[i] = user;
```

Also, to store a `String` is would need to be an array of `String`.

```
String num[]=new String[count];
```

Comment: Sensible answer. Although, if `rs2.getString(1)` is a number, `num[i]=Integer.parseInt(user);` :)